# How-To prevent Cronjob from creating a file

Tags: linux, cron

I have the following problem:

I have this cronjob:

```
* 1-23 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://yannick-w.de/Test/getData.php
```

and this cronjob always creates a new logfile. I don't need this logfile, so I want to prevent cronjob from creating it. How is this possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just redirect *stdout* and *stderr*, for example

```
 * 1-23 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://yannick-w.de/Test/getData.php > /tmp/getdata.out 2>&1
```

If no output is produced (e.g. because it has been redirected), it is not logged and not emailed to you by `cron`

BTW if you don't want any output at all replace `/tmp/getdata.out` with `/dev/null`

See [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), [cron(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html)